# Firebase Missing App configuration values in angular and ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic4

I am getting

FirebaseError: Installations: Missing App configuration values. (installations/missing-app-config-values).

when I tried to access the user token for notification.

This is my firebase-messaging-sw.js in src folder:-

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');


firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
});
```

In my environment file i have this

```
firebase: {
    apiKey: '***********************',
    authDomain: '*************',
    databaseURL: '***********',
    projectId: '********',
    storageBucket: '',
    messagingSenderId: '*********',
    vapidKey : '*******************************************'
  },
```

And in my app.component.ts

```
async ngOnInit() {
    firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
    await this.notificationsService.init();
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.platform.ready().then(async () => {
     await this.notificationsService.requestPermission();
    });
```

Ang my notification.service.ts file

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {firebase} from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/messaging';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.prod';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationsService {
init(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
            // Don't crash an error if messaging not supported
            if (!firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
                   resolve();
                   return;
            }

            const messaging = firebase.messaging();

            // Register the Service Worker
            messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);

            // Initialize your VAPI key
            messaging.usePublicVapidKey(
                  environment.firebase.vapidKey
            );

            // Optional and not covered in the article
            // Listen to messages when your app is in the foreground
            messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
                console.log(payload);
            });
            // Optional and not covered in the article
            // Handle token refresh
            messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
                messaging.getToken().then(
                (refreshedToken: string) => {
                    console.log(refreshedToken);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            });

            resolve();
        }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
  }

  requestPermission(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>(async (resolve) => {
        if (!Notification) {
            console.log('1');
            resolve();
            return;
        }
        if (!firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
            console.log('2');
            resolve();
            return;
        }
        try {
            const messaging = firebase.messaging();
            await messaging.requestPermission();

            const token: string = await messaging.getToken();

            console.log('User notifications token:', token);
        } catch (err) {
            // No notifications granted
            console.log( err);
        }

        resolve();
    });
}
}
```

When I build the project using ionic build initially browser asks me for the permission and after granting the permission I get-

```
FirebaseError: Installations: Missing App configuration values. (installations/missing-app-config-values).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this issue by add firebase tool 
`npm -g install firebase-tools` and by adding firebase project in app 
`firebase use --add`

Answer (score 4):

If someone facing same issue for **Web** then they can try below solution.

The main reason to cause this issue on **web** is version of firebase is updated.

Check your imported ***firebase-messaging.js*** and ***firebase-app.js*** versions in **firebase-messaging-sw.js** file.

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-messaging.js');
```

Only **messagingSenderId** will not work in your **firebase-messaging-sw.js** file if your firebase is version is updated. You have to provide all other params eg. **apiKey, projectId, appId** along with **messagingSenderId**.

eg.

Provide all this in your **firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "api-key",
        authDomain: "project-id.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://project-id.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "project-id",
        storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "sender-id",
        appId: "app-id",
});
```

Comment: Is it secure to post al this data in the service worker?

Answer (score 1):

i already got the same error in my project, but in my project i was working only with Angular(without Ionic ). To solve that i ran the command :

> firebase init

And select all settings again. Do you using the firebase CLI ? If didn't,  is strongly recomendly do that. You can install the firebase-tools and start project no need copy and paste auth using the command:

> npm install -g firebase-tools
>   The full documentation is here:
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/?authuser=0

Comment: Aniket i compare your code with one of my projects, and the entry point of :  firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase) code is inside of my app.module.ts, not in the app.component.

Comment: Where in app.module.ts?

Comment: Inside the import section, you can use the [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) to make the communication with firebase more simple.

Comment: ```AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),```
I did this but stil i m getting same error

Comment: What is your angular version ?

Comment: Do you removed the old configuration of firebase before configure the angularfiremodule ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200596/discussion-between-aniket-and-zeno-franca-junior).